# Visual Studio 2010 -SVN showing whole file as changes despite changing any word in the file

Tags: visual-studio-2010, svn, tortoisesvn

I am using VS2010 and SVN as source control. I am facing an issue as if i am making any changes and go for show changes it is showing the whole file as changes.For example if i changes any world in my file it is showing all the file as changes. I am not able to sort it out. Please let me know if there are any setting(s) to overcome this issue.

Thanks

Comment: What tool are you using to show the differences?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you'll use GUI-differ, which can show line-ending differences in compared files, you'll see reason of your modification

You **really must** to check and change according to your needs `svn:eol-style` [property](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.ref.properties.html):

- It can some specific file(s) property, defined at the repository level
- It can be global [auto-property](http://subversion.tigris.org/faq.html#auto-props), defined in Subversion config for some (or all text/*) extensions

`svn:eol-style = native` or just missing this property is most safe way

Answer (score 1):

Check the following:

1. Does your development environment and the original one use the same tab/spacing setting? In other words, do you both use tabs or spaces for indents? If so, standardize on a common setting across the project.
2. Does your environment convert line endings automatically, such as from the Windows CR/LF to the Unix CR? It should not by default but settings may have been changed.
3. Does the file use a different encoding mechanism? For example, was the original file in UTF8 but changed to UTF16 or similar? Once again, standardize on a common setting across the project.